# How i put Ads in the middle of the article on Mediawiki

Tags: mediawiki, ads, adsense

I am researching for a long time about that. I put Adsense ads top and bottom of the article but i can't put ads in the middle of the article. I want to put ads after one or two paragraph or something like that. I've tried many times some edits on the template files and i've failed.

Comment: What kind of ads do you mean? Could you give us the code for the ads that you have already added at the top and bottom, and the code that you have tried to use for the ads in the middle?

Comment: I mean Google Adsense ads.

`<script async src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>
<!-- Responsive Mediawiki -->
<ins class="adsbygoogle"
     style="display:block"
     data-ad-client="ca-pub-7546617*******"
     data-ad-slot="3194******"
     data-ad-format="auto"></ins>
<script>
(adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
</script>`

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a MediaWiki extension to do this - it can't be done with an unmodified MediaWiki installation, as things like `<script>` tags are disabled in wikitext for security reasons. Luckily, the [Widgets extension](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:Widgets) together with the [AdSense widget](https://www.mediawikiwidgets.org/AdSense) appears to do exactly what you need.

The extension works by adding a special code to your wikitext that looks like this: `{{#widget:WidgetName|param1=value1|param2=value2}}`. If you allow anyone to edit your wiki, you should consider protecting the pages that you put ads on, otherwise your users will be able to remove or modify the ad code.

Comment: Can i add ads all pages with Widgets extension or should i add by one by? There are too many pages. (3216)